# Typesense Query Failing with Parentheses

Tags: angular, ionic5, typesense

I am using Ionic 5 with Angular 12, NodeJS 14 and Typesense 1.4.1. I get the following error when I try to query Typesense:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): u: Request failed with HTTP code 404 | Server said: Could not find a filter field named `(startTime` in the schema.
```

The following code builds the query:

```
searchAtlistedProEvents(asi: AtlistedSearchInfo) {
    

    if (asi.displayName === "") {
      asi.displayName = "*"
    }

    let searchParameters: SearchParams = {
        q: asi.displayName,
        query_by: "displayName",
        filter_by: this.buildFilterByString(asi),
        sort_by: this.buildSortByString(asi)
    }

    const typesenseClient = new typesense.Client({
      nodes: [{
        host: "my-server.a1.typesense.net",
        port: 443,
        protocol: "https",
      }],
      apiKey: this.TYPESENSE_SEARCH_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
      connectionTimeoutSeconds: 2,
    });
    
    return typesenseClient.collections("atlistedProEventNewIndex").documents().search(searchParameters).then((doc) => {
      console.log("TYPSENSE RESPONSE HERE doc", doc);
      return doc;
    })

  }

buildFilterByString(asi: AtlistedSearchInfo) {
    let days = asi.days.map((day: Date) => {
      const start = new Date(day.valueOf());
      const end = new Date(day.valueOf());

      start.setHours(asi.startTimeOfDay.getHours(), asi.startTimeOfDay.getMinutes());
      end.setHours(asi.endTimeOfDay.getHours(), asi.endTimeOfDay.getMinutes());

      const fbStart = Number(firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(start).seconds);
      const fbEnd = Number(firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(end).seconds);


      return [fbStart, fbEnd];
    });

    let filterByString = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
      filterByString += "(startTime:<=" + days[i][0] + " && " + "stopTime:>=" + days[i][1] + ") ";
      if (i < days.length - 1) {
        filterByString += " || ";
      }

    }

    filterByString += " && eventRate:<=" + asi.eventRate + " && remainingSlots:>=" + asi.remainingSlots + " && ";
    filterByString += "location:(" + asi.location[0] + ", " + asi.location[1] + ", " + asi.locationRadius + "mi)";

    console.log("THis is final filterByString buildFilterByString", filterByString);

    return filterByString;

  }
```

When I change the following code to not include parentheses and just query a single date I am successful:

```
let filterByString = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
      filterByString += "startTime:<=" + days[i][0] + " && " + "stopTime:>=" + days[i][1] + " ";
      if (i < days.length - 1) {
        filterByString += " || ";
      }
```

The problem starts when bringing in parentheses for complex queries, but it says here that these queries are supported:

https://github.com/typesense/typesense/issues/281

Where they state:
"Yes, nested filter expressions are supported in this build as well"

For your reference, this is the filterBy string generated:

```
(startTime:<=1666972800 && stopTime:>=1667001600)  && eventRate:<=55 && remainingSlots:>=1 && location:(32.4059605, -99.4936912, 25mi)
```

Comment: I have a workaround now where I use MultiSearch instead and the filter_by expression does not have parentheses around startTime and stopTime.

Comment: Could you confirm that you're running Typesense Server `0.24.0.rcn17` or above? Only those builds support complex expressions.

Comment: I think you are correct in that my version is too low.

Comment: You don't need to have parentheses when there are only AND conditions, and OR conditions are not supported yet

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `startTime` field is nested, so you should reference it as `times.startTime` (if the object field is `times`)